# How can i figure out the type of all the scripts in the directory

Tags: unix

I want to know How can i figure out the type of all the scripts in the directory "/usr/bin" ?

Comment: `for i in /usr/bin/*; do [ -x "$i" -a ! -d "$i" ] && file "$i"; done` (or just `file /usr/bin/*`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`file(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=file&sektion=1) which identifies file types based on [magic numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)  Wrap this in a shell script like the one below to get a listing of the directory.

```
for a in /usr/bin/*; do
    file ${a}
done
```

IIRC by default the output will include the file name.

Comment: It means i have to write a shell script ?

Comment: and How can I understand if a file is a script or not?

Comment: @Ebrahim abbasi - The 'file' utility will tell you.  The shell script just goes over all the directory and invokes it.  Try running 'file' on a few shell scripts and binaries and see what it produces.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file` command:

```
file /usr/bin/*
```